# Can parameter type and count be specified by a template

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a function template inside a regular (non-template) class, which allocates a derived class with the needed parameters and returns a pointer to the base class:

```
class Factory {
public:
    BaseClass_T * createObject(parameters) { return new Derived_T(parameters); }
};
```

So far I've only been using templates where parameters vary in type, but are always the same count. Since my different derived classes have different constructor signatures, I wonder if there is a way to template that and specify the generated function's parameter type and count via a template, something like this:

```
Factory f;
f.createObject<Derived1, void>(); // create createObject() for Derivev1() constructor
f.createObject<Derived2, int, double>(); // create createObject() for Derived2(int, double) constructor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variadic template:

```
#include <utility>

struct BaseClass_T { ~virtual BaseClass_T() = default; };

struct Factory
{
    template <typename Der, typename ...Args>
    BaseClass_T * create(Args &&... args)
    { 
        return new Der(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

An even better design would be for your factory to return `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass_T>`:

```
#include <memory>

struct SaneFactory
{
    template <typename Der, typename ...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<BaseClass_T> create(Args &&... args)
    { 
        return std::make_unique<Der>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why does the destructor have to be `= default`? Doesn't it suffice to just declare it virtual? After all, there can only be one destructor, no?

Comment: Also, I am immediately using that pointer to add it into an object tree which manages the object, so I think I don't need the `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @dgtech: the destructor needs to be defined, either explicitly or implicitly. Just declaring it suppresses its implicit definition.

Comment: @dgtech: You always need `unique_ptr` unless you hate yourself or your users. There's no added cost, and it makes the code self-documenting. Write What You Mean, rather than something that accidentally happens to work. In this case, what you mean is that the factory function returns a parcel of responsibility.

Comment: I am confused, it says "std::unique_ptr is a smart pointer that retains sole ownership of an object through a pointer and destroys that object when the unique_ptr goes out of scope" - sounds like my object will be deleted in the end of the function where it is created, which is the last thing I want.

Comment: @dgtech: The other part of your code should also accept a unique pointer and transfer ownership across. That is, you'll need to fix all parts of your program that concern ownership. Failing that, the calling code can say `old_broken_function(sane_factory.create<Foo>().release())` to document that it is now managing ownership. But at least your factory can be written properly.

Comment: Ah, you mean I should keep unique_ptr in the "parent" objects as well, unfortunately that is not an option, since the object tree is part of a C API, I am just using some C++ in the actual object to save on development time using the extra features.

Comment: @dgtech: You can use `release()` at API boundaries, so that the explicit responsibility transfer is part of a small, tight, testable wrapper interface. But keep the core of your code clean. In other words, minimize the mental effort required to understand what your code does.